# Is there a code cleanup tool like codemaid for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatting, refactoring, code-cleanup

Some of you may suggest `Checkstyle` but it only highlights/points to cleanup and doesn't really cleanup the code like [Codemaid](http://www.codemaid.net/).

Comment: Could you please be more specific what you're missing from _Source > Clean Up..._ (which can be also triggered on save)?

Comment: For which language (Java, C/C++, ...)? In case of C/C++ see _Window > Preferences: C/C++ > Editor > Save Actions_.

Comment: @howlger Source clean up only does a part of what Codemaid or Jindent does. I cant apply formatting to the whole project at once as well.

Comment: What can Codemaid (and Jindent) do more than Eclipse for which language? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Long dead, but I had the same question, after recently switching back to Java from .Net.  I think you are looking for Source>Sort Members... and Source>Format.

Answer (score 1):

**Jindent** - The Java code formatter plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Thank you! Works great but its not free :(